# Regarding downloading bulk data through Python in Excel

Tags: python, excel, odoo-8, bulk-load

Basically, I have created an Excel addon which connects to Odoo ERP server using xmlrpc and gets an array object. 
Everything is working well except when number of records are huge, it fails and throws memory error.

Could someone suggest a better practice to achieve this functionality where the data volume is huge. Below code I am trying on server side in Python.

```
sql = " SELECT * FROM table" 
cr.execute(sql) # 1 Million records, Executes fine
data = cr.fetchall() #Fails and gives memory error
return data
```

Thanks,
Burhan

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
  [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**iter**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__)

```
sql = " SELECT * FROM table" 
cr.execute(sql) # 1 Million records, Executes fine
for row in cr:
    doSomething(row)
```